# How do I display user location as soon as permission is granted?

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, permissions, location

I am creating a map application and I have an issue, where the app won't show the user location once permission is granted.

**Packages Used**

1. permission_handler
2. google_maps_flutter.dart'

I have got the location permission thing sorted, but the app doesn't show the user location as soon as the permissions have been granted. If I re-run the app, then it does.

This is frustrating the hell out of me and I would appreciate it, if somebody could show me how to display the users' current location once the permissions have been granted?

Here is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ManchesterMaps/models/locales.dart';
import 'package:ManchesterMaps/widgets/drawers/map_drawer.dart';
import 'package:ManchesterMaps/widgets/home_pages/my_places/list_places.dart';
import 'package:ManchesterMaps/widgets/home_pages/settings/preferences.dart';
import 'package:ManchesterMaps/widgets/home_pages/the_map/the_map.dart';
import 'package:ManchesterMaps/widgets/home_pages/uni_security/uni_security_info.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:circular_bottom_navigation/circular_bottom_navigation.dart';
import 'package:circular_bottom_navigation/tab_item.dart';

import './theme.dart' as Theme;

void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  PageController controller = PageController();
  int selected = 0;


//BottomBar list
  List<TabItem> tabItems = List.of([
    new TabItem(Icons.home, "Campus Map", Theme.UniColors.primaryColour[500],
        labelStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Theme.UniColors.primaryColour[500],
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
    new TabItem(Icons.search, "Search", Theme.UniColors.primaryColour[500],
        labelStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Theme.UniColors.primaryColour[500],
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
    new TabItem(Icons.place, "My Places", Theme.UniColors.primaryColour[500],
        labelStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Theme.UniColors.primaryColour[500],
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
    new TabItem(
        Icons.security, "Security Info", Theme.UniColors.primaryColour[500],
        labelStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Theme.UniColors.primaryColour[500],
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
    new TabItem(Icons.settings, "Settings", Theme.UniColors.primaryColour[500],
        labelStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Theme.UniColors.primaryColour[300],
            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
  ]);

  // Show Map Page
  CircularBottomNavigationController _navigationController =
      new CircularBottomNavigationController(0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Locale myLocale = Localizations.localeOf(context);
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        // A class which loads the translations from JSON files
        const AppLocalizationsDelegate(),
        // Built-in localization of basic text for Material widgets
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        // Built-in localization for text direction LTR/RTL
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: [
        const Locale('en', ''),
        const Locale('fr', ''),
        const Locale('ar', ''),
        const Locale('de', ''),
        const Locale('es', ''),
        const Locale('hi', ''),
      ],
      onGenerateTitle: (BuildContext context) =>
          AppLocalizations.of(context).title,
      color: Theme.UniColors.primaryColour[300],
      theme: Theme.uniThemeData,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            PageView(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: TheMap(),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Center(child: Text("Page 2")),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: ListPlaces(),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: UniSecurityInfo(),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Preferences(),
                ),
              ],
              controller: controller,
              onPageChanged: (num) {
                controller.animateToPage(
                  _navigationController.value,
                  curve: Curves.ease,
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        extendBody: true,
        bottomNavigationBar: CircularBottomNavigation(
          tabItems,
          controller: _navigationController,
          selectedCallback: (int selected) {
            _navigationController.value = selected;

            switch (selected) {
              case 0:
                {
                  controller.animateToPage(0,
                      curve: Curves.easeIn,
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300));
                  break;
                }
              case 1:
                {
                  controller.animateToPage(1,
                      curve: Curves.easeIn,
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300));
                  break;
                }
              case 2:
                {
                  controller.animateToPage(2,
                      curve: Curves.easeIn,
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300));
                  break;
                }
              case 3:
                {
                  controller.animateToPage(3,
                      curve: Curves.easeIn,
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300));
                  break;
                }
              case 4:
                {
                  controller.animateToPage(4,
                      curve: Curves.easeIn,
                      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300));
                  break;
                }
            }
          },
        ),
        drawer: MapDrawer(),
      ),
    );
  }
}


import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class TheMap extends StatefulWidget {
  TheMap({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  _TheMapState createState() => _TheMapState();
}

class _TheMapState extends State<TheMap> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  PermissionStatus _status;
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _mapController = Completer();

  LatLng _centre;
  Position currentLocation;
  MapType _currentMapType = MapType.normal;

  FutureOr<GoogleMapController> get controller => null;

// check permissions
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    // Check location permission has been granted
    PermissionHandler()
        .checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup
            .locationWhenInUse) //check permission returns a Future
        .then(_updateStatus); // handling in callback to prevent blocking UI
  }

  //double distanceInMeters = await Geolocator().distanceBetween(52.2165157, 6.9437819, 52.3546274, 4.8285838);

  // method that is called on map creation and takes a MapController as a parameter
  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    PermissionHandler()
        .checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup
            .locationWhenInUse) //check permission returns a Future
        .then(_updateStatus); // handling in callback to prevent blocking UI

      _mapController.complete(
          controller); // manages camera function (position, animation, zoom).
    }


  Future<Position> locateUser() async {
    return Geolocator()
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
  }

  //TODO: Get Users' location
  getUserLocation() async {
    currentLocation = await locateUser();
    setState(() {
      _centre = LatLng(currentLocation.latitude ?? 53.467125,
          currentLocation.longitude ?? -2.233966);
    });
    print('centre $_centre');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        GoogleMap(
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          initialCameraPosition: // required parameter that sets the starting camera position. Camera position describes which part of the world you want the map to point at.
              CameraPosition(
                  target: LatLng(53.467125, -2.233966), zoom: 14.5, tilt: 0.0),
          scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
          tiltGesturesEnabled: true,
          compassEnabled: true,
          rotateGesturesEnabled: true,
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          mapType: _currentMapType,
          zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  // check permissions when app is resumed
  // this is when permissions are changed in app settings outside of app
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      PermissionHandler()
          .checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse)
          .then(_updateStatus);
    }
    print("STATE -> $state");
  }

  /*void _askPermission() {
    PermissionHandler().requestPermissions(
        [PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]).then(_onStatusRequested);
  }*/

  void _onStatusRequested(Map<PermissionGroup, PermissionStatus> statuses) {
    final status = statuses[PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse];
    if (status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      // On iOS if "deny" is pressed, open App Settings
      PermissionHandler().openAppSettings();
    } else {
      //_updateStatus(status);
      print("STATUS -> $status");
    }
  }

  void _updateStatus(PermissionStatus status) {
    if (status != _status) {
      // check status has changed
      setState(() {
        _status = status; // update
        _onMapCreated(controller);
      });
    } else {
      if (status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        print("REQUESTING PERMISSION");
        PermissionHandler().requestPermissions(
            [PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]).then(_onStatusRequested);
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

Am I missing something really obvious here?

Any help is extremely appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was receiving an target != null error and this was fixed with adding CircularProgressIndicator()

```
children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          // Login Box
          image: _buildBackgroundImage(),
        ),
      ),
      _userLocation == null
          ? CircularProgressIndicator()
          : GoogleMap(
              onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
              initialCameraPosition: // required parameter that sets the starting camera position. Camera position describes which part of the world you want the map to point at.
                  CameraPosition(
                      target: _userLocation,
                      zoom: 14.5,
                      tilt: 0.0), //LatLng(53.467125, -2.233966)
              scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
              tiltGesturesEnabled: true,
              compassEnabled: true,
              rotateGesturesEnabled: true,
              myLocationEnabled: true,
              mapType: _currentMapType,
              zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
            ),
    ],
```